# Is it possible for an Indian citizen with matriculation to get US work permit?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, working-visas, resident-permit, indian-citizens

I am 26 year old and work as PHP developer. I have passed matriculation. How can or what are the steps i should take to get work permit in USA or at any developed country for that matter?

Comment: A university education (at least a bachelor or maybe some other form of higher education) would seem a good start. IT skills do help but I don't think you stand a good chance of finding a job and/or getting a visa/work permit with only a secondary school education.

Answer (score 3):

In the US there are two kinds of work visa:

1. H1b - requires a 4-years bachelor degree or equivalent (equivalent being 3 years of professional experience for each missing year, i.e.: 12 years of experience in your case). This visa is given in limited quantities and you must secure employment with an employer who'd be willing to sponsor you, a 6-12 months before you can actually start working.
2. L1 - this visa is for intra-company transfers and requires specific experience that is needed in the US branch. Usually, at least 1 year of employment in the foreign branch is required, and recently the criteria got more strict (I've heard people being denied even with 3+ years of employment in the foreign branch). This visa doesn't have education requirements, but the employer must want to transfer you, and must be able to show that the experience you gained in the foreign branch is needed in the US branch. You cannot transfer to a different employer on this visa.

You'll have to be more specific about other countries you're interested in, but generally a minimum requirement of a bachelor degree is more or less universal.